# Concurrency in Python, multiprocess slower than single process

Tags: python, concurrency, multiprocessing

I'm currently creating a simple script that simulates a maths problem. The problem is 'The Frog Problem', presented [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZLTyX4zL2Fc) by Matt Parker of standupmaths on his YouTube channel. But basically, the problem is about a frog trying to hop from one side of a river to another on lillypads in increments. My code simulates this by subtracting a random number from the number of lillypads left and continuing until that number is 0.

This is the entire thing:

```
import random
import datetime
from multiprocessing import Pool

def frog_time(num_lillypads):
    jumps = 0
    while num_lillypads > 0:
        num_lillypads -= random.randint(1, num_lillypads)
        jumps += 1
    return jumps

def frog_run(num_lillypads, iterations=10000):
    ave = 0
    print("Running {} lillypads.".format(num_lillypads))
    for i in range(1, iterations+1):
        ave = (ave*(i-1)+frog_time(num_lillypads))/i
    return ave

def single_run(max_lillypads, iterations):
    start = datetime.datetime.now()
    results = []
    for i in range(1, max_lillypads+1):
        results.append(frog_run(i, iterations))
    time_taken = datetime.datetime.now() - start
    return time_taken

def timing_run(max_lillypads, iterations):
    start = datetime.datetime.now()
    with Pool() as pool:
        pad_nos = list(range(1, max_lillypads+1))
        results = pool.map(frog_run, range(1, max_lillypads+1))
    time_taken = datetime.datetime.now() - start
    return time_taken

def test(max=1000, iters=10000):
    print("Concurrent run")
    concurrent_time = timing_run(max, iters)
    print("Single run")
    single_time = single_run(max, iters)
    print("Single run took {} to finish.".format(single_time))
    print("Concurrent run took {} to finish.".format(concurrent_time))
```

I decided to use this as en exercise to practice concurrent programming in Python, but I expected wildly different results.
When I run this I get:

```
Single run took 0:01:55.825933 to finish.
Concurrent run took 0:02:00.110245 to finish.
```

I thought that the run that implemented multiprocessing would be at least a little bit faster, if not significantly faster, but in this case it actually takes longer!

Can anybody who knows more about python multiprocessing help me out by explaining this result? Is the overhead of creating a new process for each one of these too much to make a difference, or maybe python.random is too slow, or is there something else wrong about this?

Comment: I haven't looked at the code really but your last question is probably correct. If a single iteration isn't actually taking that much time to complete, then setting up the processes is going to take more time than just running it the first time. You could look at forcing `pool(2)` for example rather than leaving it blank which will be `cpu_count` sized which would take less time to initiate.

Comment: In general, `multiprocessing` is for CPU bound operations, and `multithreading` is for I/O bound operations. If your original is not CPU bound then it isn't going to help to be multiprocessed.

Comment: I just did this and oddly this sped it up a fair amount. I think this is probably the result I was more expecting the first time. The single run took `1:56.21` to run and the concurrent run took `1:01.48`. Could this just be a sweet-spot between setting up more processes and actually doing the computation?

Comment: As far as I can tell this is a CPU bound operation, unless random.randint() makes it I/O. Apart from that it's all arithmetic and comparison.

Comment: I agree based on what I have read. I posted an answer below that better explains what I commented here

Comment: If that answers your question, please click the check mark next to it as well @mattrea6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now, you aren't specifying an amount of processes to set up so it will default to maximum: [[source]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool)

> processes is the number of worker processes to use. If processes is None then the number returned by os.cpu_count() is used.

Each worker process takes `x` amount of time to set up.

So, let's use some *arbitrary* values to see how we do:
- the function takes 120 seconds to run in one process
- each process takes 5 seconds to start
- each new process can divide the workload equally

If that were the case:

- No multiprocessing: 120 seconds
- Multiprocessing with 2 processes: 60 seconds + 10 seconds = 70 seconds
- Multiprocessing with 3 processes: 40 seconds + 15 seconds = 55 seconds
- Multiprocessing with 4 processes: 30 seconds + 20 seconds = 50 seconds
- Multiprocessing with 5 processes: 24 seconds + 25 seconds = 49 seconds
- Multiprocessing with 6 processes: 20 seconds + 30 seconds = 50 seconds
- Multiprocessing with 7 processes: 17 seconds + 35 seconds = 52 seconds

So, there is a point where you don't have gains by using multiprocessing, or you can limit the amount of processes to where you are still saving more time than the time lost creating the processes.

If you use `pool(2)` or `pool(3)`, etc. you will probably see time gains and then losses again. At much larger scale, the more processes you have the better off you would be, but at small testing scale that may not be the case.

Comment: I thought this was the right answer but I just tried something. Specifying more processes sped it up this time.
```
Run with 1 processes took 0:01:58.52.
Run with 2 processes took 0:01:01.63.
Run with 3 processes took 0:00:40.12.
Run with 4 processes took 0:00:31.14.
Run with 5 processes took 0:00:24.79.
Run with 6 processes took 0:00:20.76.
Run with 7 processes took 0:00:18.04.
Run with 8 processes took 0:00:16.04.
Run with 9 processes took 0:00:14.02.
Run with 10 processes took 0:00:13.11.
Run with 11 processes took 0:00:12.87.
Run with 12 processes took 0:00:11.92.
```

Comment: And do an `import os` `os.cpu_count()` and what is that?

Comment: Just in case: `>>> multiprocessing.cpu_count()
12
>>>`

Comment: `os.cpu_count()` returns the same result

Comment: So when you run it without any number it takes a long time but when you run it with 12 it doesn't?

Comment: Yep, that's right. Is there a way to view the number of current processes at runtime?

Comment: I just ran your code as posted and got: `Single run took 0:01:17.233414 to finish.` and `Concurrent run took 0:00:14.901165 to finish.`. What you could do, and what I normally do anyway, is to manually do an `cpu = os.cpu_count()` and then send that to `Pool(cpu)` which you could print if you wanted as well.

Comment: I just copy-pasted and ran my code from the question a few times to check and it seems to run in ~13s every time now. I can't recreate the error I had in the first place. Maybe I just had terrible CPU load the first time I ran it?

Comment: Could have been other processes running preventing it from actually running on multiple processes.

Comment: Odd, because I'm certain I remember the output being out-of-order when I ran it that first time too, so it was running on different processes. Thank you for your help, even if I may never know the real reason now :// :)